# pointer to view in "view based application"

Tags: objective-c, xcode

hi
I created a "view based application " and I have three classes:
-MyAppViewController;
-Item (UIView subclass);
-MySingleton;

I need to call from item class, a method of MyAppViewController so I need to create a pointer, but the problem is that I do not understand when you create the link:

in singleton:

```
h
@class MyAppViewController;

        ...

@interface MySingleton : NSObject  {

        id plCall;
        ...

}
        ...
@property (nonatomic, retain) id plCall; //and @synthesize in .m
        ...
```

the item:

```
[[MySingleton sharedMySingleton].plCall myMethod];
```

but I miss the connection to the controller that should be so:

```
[MySingleton sharedMySingleton].plCall = MyAppViewController;
```

but this does not happen because it is a "view based application " and never i allocated directly the view

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get your controller object created by xib, you can do this in your controller's `-viewDidLoad`

```
@implementation MyAppViewController
...

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [MySingleton sharedMySingleton].plCall = self;
}
...
@end
```

Comment: works great! works, but I got these two warnings: 1)method '.myMethos' not found (returd type defaults to 'id') and 2) No '-myMethod' method found; why?

Comment: 1) define -myMethod in your object's class(say, SomeClass)' header. 2) change your plCall's type from id to SomeClass. 3) or change your plCall's type from id to id<someprotocol>, and define -myMethod in someprotocol

Comment: solved: I forgot the import and @ class:) in item, thanks again!